# Use on-premises data gateway in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an on-premises data gateway service in Azure, which connects to an on-premises SQL Server (this is a standard Azure service, which can be configured).

When I am in the data gateway service in the Azure Portal, I can see that I can "Read and write data using logic apps" right off the bat.

How do I use my newly created on-premises SQL server gateway in Azure Data Factory? I have found some videos on how a gateway is set up, but this I have already done. I simply need to create a new data pipeline, where i make a COPY DATA activity, so I can copy data from this on-premises SQL server to a Cloud Azure SQL server using the gateway.

Comment: the "normal" data gateway isn't for Data Factory, you'll need an [integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal#create-a-pipeline) or configure a [vnet with a private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such requirement to setup any kind of data gateway when accessing on-premises SQL Server using Azure Data Factory.

Azure Data Factory (ADF) makes it very easy to connect with on-premises SQL Server and copy the data to Cloud. You just simply need to create **Self-hosted Integration Runtime (IR)** in your local machine which will allow you to access the data. Refer this simple step-by-step official tutorial by Microsoft to [Create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory).

Once your Self-hosted IR created, you just need to use ADF's **Copy data** tool and configure your source and destination settings. Use the self-hosted IR which you have created and run the pipeline.

Refer this detailed third-party tutorial to [Copy data from On-premises data store to an Azure data store using Azure Data Factory](https://www.sqlshack.com/copy-data-from-on-premises-data-store-to-an-azure-data-store-using-azure-data-factory/). Easy step-by-step guidance is provided here.

Comment: If you have to install software and that software bridges on-premises data and the cloud, wouldn't that be a "gateway"?  I think most would agree that's the definition of the term.